# How to check that a typical map is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, smooth-functions

I'm currently doing a geometry course, and I'm struggling a bit on the practical side of how to show a map is a smooth homeomorphism. Can we go through the following example from one of my problem sheets, which is made up from pretty typical and not too "messy" functions?

I want to show that

$$\sigma(u,v) = (u+v, 2uv, u^2+v^2)$$

is a smooth homeomorphism from the set $U=\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2: u>v\}$ to its image.

I think that we need to show that is smooth bijection, and has a smooth inverse, and that we could do this by showing that it maps all open sets to open sets.

I'm not really sure how to show this in a way that is efficient and accurate, though, can someone provide me with the general method for showing something like this?

Comment: To show something is a smooth homeomorphism onto its image, it suffices to show that it is injective, smooth (=infinitly differentiable) and has injective derivative everywhere. The first and latter are computations, while you can mostly argue that your "not too messy" function is smooth by inspection. In this case, $\sigma$ is comprised of polynomial functions, which are always smooth. Can you do the computations for the other properties?

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend I see, thank you.